# Linting SQLite Commands in Visual Studio Code within a Python Script

Tags: python, sqlite, visual-studio-code, lint, pylance

Is there a way to lint SQLite commands contained within a `.execute()` method call for a database connection object (from Python's `sqlite3` library) from within `Visual Studio Code`? I've seen this done in `Intellij IDEA` but this is not my preference IDE. I should also note that I am using Pylance as my linter.

I've tried searching the settings of Visual Studio Code, specifically under the Python Linter settings, but this has produced no leads.

Comment: [edit] to show a code example please (a [mre]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use command `pip install cs50` in terminal to install [cs50](https://cs50.readthedocs.io/libraries/cs50/python/) package.

Then you can use codes `db = cs50.SQL("sqlite:///file.db")  # For SQLite, file.db must exist` to connect the SQLite.

There exists `.execute` method as well.

The example in the document of cs50 can help you better understand:

```
import cs50

db = cs50.SQL("sqlite:///file.db")

rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM foo")

rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar = ? AND baz = ?", 1, 2)
rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar IN (?) AND baz IN (?)", [1, 2], [3, 4])

rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar = :bar AND baz = :baz", bar=1, baz=2)
rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar IN (:bar) AND baz IN (:baz)", bar=[1, 2], baz=[3, 4])

id = db.execute("INSERT INTO foo (bar, baz) VALUES(?, ?)", 1, 2)
id = db.execute("INSERT INTO foo (bar, baz) VALUES(:bar, :baz)", bar=1, baz=2)

n = db.execute("UPDATE foo SET bar = ?, baz = ?", 1, 2)
n = db.execute("UPDATE foo SET bar = :bar, baz = :baz", bar=1, baz=2)

n = db.execute("DELETE FROM foo WHERE bar = ? AND baz = ?", 1, 2)
n = db.execute("DELETE FROM foo WHERE bar = :bar AND baz = :baz", bar=1, baz=2)
```

The syntax error display of SQL statements is **not supported** for Pylance. You can read [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/2291) on github for the reason. At present, there are no similar extensions in the market to meet this requirement. You have to check the correctness of the SQL statements yourself.

Comment: thanks for this. It's unfortunate that Pylance refuses to add this functionality when IntelliJ IDEA has built-in linting software that handles this. Not enough to make me switch IDEs, but it would be a nice touch in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install mysql-connector-python package:

```
pip install mysql-connector-python
```

Then create a Python script to connect to the database, and I can give you a simple example which uses the select statement and print line by line:

```
import mysql.connector

conn = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    database="dbname",
    user="user",
    password="password")

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table")

for row in cursor:
    print(row)
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, just a couple follow ups on this: (1) By using this library is the SQL command typed within the .execute method linted? For example will it pick up on syntax errors or do auto complete suggests? (2) Can you connect to a SQLite database?

Comment: @Jon_Gendron I'm sorry that this is suitable for mysql. I'll give another answer for SQLite. And intellisense is not access for sql syntax in python file.